# jQuery/Javascript - Check whether an element exists in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to check whether an element exists in an iframe or not? I know it is impossible to manipulate something on a foreign host because of the Same Origin Policy. But what if I just want to find out if an element exists?

```
<body id="parent">
  <iframe src="foreign host">
    <span id="exist">
      Yes, Yes. I'am here.
    </span>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

I tried to figure this out with jquery:

```
$('iframe:first').contents().find('#exist').length throws out a
```

Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument' error

I do not wanna change something in the foreign document. So there is no danger. Why is this denied?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: But with read-only access you could e.g. throw up a phishing site which loaded my online bank in an iframe then read all my bank details out of the frame as I used it.

Comment: @Rup You are right. So I really have an Same Origins Policy "Problem". thx

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but the Same Origin Policy does not allow it because you can read personal information on another domain or do a phising just embeding a full document iframe.

There are alternative solutions:

- Run the browser without security: p.e.: 'chromium-browser --disable-web-security'
- Make a proxy and do the http connection like a client. Make the proxy in the same domain as your page.

If it's in the same domain any other comments can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an ID to your iframe tag like so:

```
<iframe src="blah.html" id="blah"></iframe>
```

You can then reference that iframe in jQuery by doing:

```
var iframe = $("#blah");
```

Once you've done that you can use the contents() function on the iframe var you just created to access its DOM.